# Is mongodb,couchdb consistent on single node?

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, document-database

I have read that document databases are eventually consistent when on multiple nodes, what about the installation is only on single node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of eventual consistency arises in a multi-node setup because of the possibility of nodes getting disconnected (partitioned) due to a variety of issues. When they connect again, they sync with each other (depending on the setup and database) and regain a consistent state. Hence the term 'eventually consistent'

Since there's no such possibility in a single node setup, in this setup, both databases can be considered to be strongly consistent.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a single node is always consistent, as consistency is "all nodes see the same data at the same time" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem))

However, you're mistaken that document databases are all the same. NoSQL databases have a lot of variety, so avoid painting with a broad brush when you can.

MongoDB, when using secondary nodes, is "eventually consistent by default" ([source](https://www.mongodb.com/faq)), but to me that implies that you can configure it to behave differently.

CouchDB, on the other hand, is always eventually consistent by design. ([source](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/consistency.html))